# Entity Framework Skip and Take too slow

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

The following code achieves what I require, reading 10000 rows at a time:

```
var query = repository.Subscribers.ToList().Skip(numberToSkip).Take(numberInBatch);
```

Is there an alternative which will make this faster?

Here's the full code:

```
protected static string ContactUrl = BaseUrl + "/api/contact";  


protected static int NumberInBatch = 10000;
protected static int NumberToSkip = 10000;
protected static int NumberToCountUpto = 100000;

public static string GetSubscribers(int numberToSkip, int numberInBatch)
    {
        using (var repository = new SubscriberEntities())
        {
            var index = 0;
            string output = null;
            var query = repository.Subscribers.ToList().Skip(numberToSkip).Take(numberInBatch);

            foreach (var subscriber in query)
            {
                var telephone = ContactHelper.GetTelephoneFromEmail(subscriber.EmailAddress);


                string requestCreateContact = RequestHelper.CreateContact(subscriber.EmailAddress, telephone);
                if (index > 0) output = output + ",";
                output = output + (requestCreateContact);

            }
            return output;
        }
    }

    //Batch Create
    public static void SendBatchCreate()
    {

        for (int i = NumberToSkip; i < NumberToCountUpto; i += NumberInBatch)
        {
            var requestCreateMultipleContacts = GetSubscribersAndCreateContacts(i, NumberInBatch);

            RequestHelper.SubmitPostRequest(requestCreateMultipleContacts, ContactUrl);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: A simple way to speed up the `Skip().Take()` LINQ expression is to use `GetRange()` instead. I learnt that the hard way!

Answer (score 16):

I would first suggest [logging the database operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464) to see what SQL is executed.  EF may not be running the SQL you think it is.

**The red flag I see is that you call ToList before the Skip and Take.**  Generally in LINQ statements, ToList forces execution immediately.

This suggests your EF code is pulling every record from the table up front, building a list, and *then* applying the Skip/Take to the list.  If that's the case, the logged SQL should show a select statement without any filtering.

I suspect what you really *want* to do is run the ToList after the Skip and Take.  This should apply the filtering inside the executed SQL, but the logging will show you for sure.

Comment: Calling `ToList` will *definitely* materialize the query, and the rest of the chained LINQ calls operate with *Linq-to-Objects* in memory, on the client. A profiler will show something like `SELECT [all fields] FROM Subscribers`, embedded in an `sp_executesql` call.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> var query = repository.Subscribers.ToList().Skip(numberToSkip).Take(numberInBatch);
>
> foreach (var subscriber in query)
> {
>     var telephone = ContactHelper.GetTelephoneFromEmail(subscriber.EmailAddress);
>
>
>     string requestCreateContact = RequestHelper.CreateContact(subscriber.EmailAddress, telephone);
>     if (index > 0) output = output + ",";
>     output = output + (requestCreateContact);
>
> }
> return output;
> ```

The name `query` isn't appropriate here, because you've materialized the actual query with `ToList` and filtered it with *Linq-to-Objects*.

This would do it:

```
var query = repository.Subscribers.Skip(numberToSkip).Take(numberInBatch);
```

Now the query hasn't executed yet, *because you haven't iterated it*. That's how *Linq-to-Entities* works (*Linq-to-SQL* works the same way), the materialization of the query is deferred to the very last possible moment, which enables you to return the `IQueryable<T>` and keep adding to it (say, with a `Where` clause), all the while without hitting the database server.

You don't *need* to call `ToList`: *iterating* it is enough.

---

Another performance-related issue you have here, is that you're concatenating the `output` string in a loop. This is bad, because a `string` is an immutable object in .NET, so you're creating many, many, many objects here, without even noticing.

The solution is to use a `StringBuilder` instead of straight concatenations. This code should run much faster with 10K rows:

```
var query = repository.Subscribers.Skip(numberToSkip).Take(numberInBatch);
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var subscriber in query)
{
    var telephone = ContactHelper.GetTelephoneFromEmail(subscriber.EmailAddress);
    var contact = RequestHelper.CreateContact(subscriber.EmailAddress, telephone);

    if (index > 0) // is this condition ever true?
    {
        builder.Append(",");
    }

    builder.Append(contact);
}

return builder.ToString();
```